Skaffold keeps restarting a container if it doesn't have a listener
When running skaffold dev with a container that has a listener (in this case Express), the container hangs as expected.
If I remove the listener with simple executable code, it keeps running it over and over.
I tried to search in the documentation but all I can see is that Skaffold should re-run the code only if you make changes.
I expected Skaffold would terminate the container after the run.
Are the restarts a normal behavior? Should I only add to Skaffold services that have listeners?
The following code results in seeing the "test" console.log every few seconds.
skaffold.yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./dpl/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: myuser/myworker
      context: myworker
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .

index.ts
//import express from 'express'

//const app = express()


console.log('test')

//app.listen(3000, () => {
//  console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
//})

package.json
{
  "name": "myworker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --omit=dev
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]


One reason that the container keeps on restarting is because of ts-node-dev in your package.json. ts-node-dev is a tool that automatically watches for changes in your TypeScript files and restarts the application whenever it detects a modification. There is also a possibility that when you run skaffolds dev, it enters a development loop that monitors your code for changes. While Skaffold itself might not be restarting the container due to the missing listener, ts-node-dev is triggering restarts independently.
You can try this approach of replacing ts-node-dev. You can consider using npm run build to compile your TypeScript code before running the application. This might create a build that won't be restarted by file changes. Or you can consider disabling the automatic file watchingof ts-node-dev behaviour with --no-poll flag:
"scripts": {
  "start": "ts-node-dev --no-poll src/index.ts"
}

However, you'll need to manually rebuild and restart the container whenever you  make code changes.
